# Circumventing Stale Element Exceptions in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have read several articles on this site regarding around the StaleElementReferenceException and am aware that this error is caused by the element no longer being in the site's DOM. What I am trying to do is click the bottom links on this webpage in order to go on and see the next page's listings. I have tried a few ways around this exception being given to me, and haven't found any to work. Here is an example of the code I have tried, and what I thought it might accomplish.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Hank\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Unusual%20Old%20Guadalajara')
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
action = ActionChains(driver)
page_links = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class^=market_paging_pagelink]')))
try:
    action.move_to_element(page_links[1]).click().perform()
except StaleElementReferenceException as Exception:
    print("Exception received, trying again")
    time.sleep(5)
    page_links = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class^=market_paging_pagelink]')))
    action.move_to_element(page_links[1]).click().perform()
```

I was hoping that this code segment would attempt to move to the element at the bottom, click it, or return the error message, and try again, succeeding the second time. Instead, the code simply throws the error again. If my question has already been answered, please direct me to the relevant link.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I normally go for is to click Next page until the button gets disabled/invisible.

Here's a working example based on your page. You should obviously do whatever relevant in the `while` loop; I chose to capture prices for the sake of example.

```
url="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Unusual%20Old%20Guadalajara"
driver.get(url)

next_button=wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'searchResults_btn_next')))

# capture the start value from "Showing x-xx of 22 results"
#need this to check against later
ref_val=wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'searchResults_start'))).text

while next_button.get_attribute('class') == 'pagebtn':
    next_button.click()
    #wait until ref_val has changed
    wait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'searchResults_start'))).text != ref_val)

    # ====== Do whatever relevant here =============================
    page_num=wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.market_paging_pagelink.active'))).text
    print(f"Prices from page {page_num}")
    prices = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee']")))
    for price in prices:
        print(price.text)
    #================================================================

    #get the new reference value
    ref_val = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchResults_start'))).text
```

Comment: Great! I looked at your script and it makes sense, you use the class of the button changing when it becomes invisible to stop the script and keep it running only while the button is clickable. I'll use this, thank you very much! However, I do have one question. I am not familiar with the use of lambda, what is this and what is it used for?

Comment: That's right. As for lambda, this is a Python concept (rather than Selenium). Lambdas are just one liner functions, useful if you know you will need to call them in just one place in your code. This particular one translates to "check if ref_val has changed". Which placed inside webdriver wait reads "wait until ref_val has changed".

Comment: I marked the answer as correct, however, I still need clarification on one thing. Will this get the prices for the first page, too? Or will it not get those prices because the next button has already been clicked? Or will it GET those prices because the ref value has not changed? Thanks.

Comment: In this particular example, no. You get the ref value, move to the next page, get prices (for that page), then check if ref value has changed. You could copy that "Do whatever relevant here" block in above the while loop if you want prices for the 1st page for a quick solution. Better yet you could turn it into a function and call that function to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Sorry, just a correction on my last comment (as you can't edit after 5 minutes). You don't "then check if ref value has changed", you then get the new ref value.